# Is there a name for a morphism of schemes which is an inverse limit of schemes such that the transition maps are all open immersions?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a name for a morphism of schemes which is an inverse limit of schemes such that the transition maps are all open immersions?

To be more precise, I have a scheme $S$, and a functor $U: I \to Sch(S)$ from a directed poset to the category of $S$-schemes of **finite type** such that the image of each morphism of $I$ is an open immersion. I then consider the inverse limit $U = lim U_i$.

The question is: do schemes of the form $U$ have a name?

Motivation: I want the category of schemes of finite type over a base, but I also want the category to contain the residue fields of all the points of any scheme (function fields), and also to contain fibre products. Surely this already exists and has a name?

Comment: Do you mean a filtered limit? In this case this is just a filtered intersection of open subschemes. These were studied in the paper "Infinite intersection of open subschemes and the Hilbert scheme of points" by Roy M. Skjelnes and Charles Walter http://www.math.kth.se/~skjelnes/Pdffiler/infinteint.pdf.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the most important part: that they are of finite type over a base scheme.

Comment: Is what you want different from schemes which are "essentially of finite type" over $S$?

Comment: Hi ulrich. I've seen "essentially of finite type" defined as "a localisation of a scheme of finite type". If localisation means localisation at a point then this is no good for my purposes. If on the other hand localisation means any inverse limit of open subschemes then this is exactly what I want. Do you know of a reference where I can find these definitions?

Comment: I don't think localisation is meant to be at a point but I don't know a reference where this is precisely defined, though it is commonly used. In EGA a map of rings $A \to B$ is defined to be essentially of finte type if $B$ is any localisation of a fintely generated $A$ algebra, but there doesn't seem to be any definition for general schemes.

Comment: Ok, got it. Its EGA IV 1.3.8 for the affine version.

Comment: I guess the obvious extension to schemes would be to take the definition of "finite type" for schemes and replace finite type with ess. of finite type whenever it refers to an algebra.

Comment: This does seem to be the only natural thing to do. However, as opposed to the finite type case, it is not clear that if a morphism $Spec(B) \to Spec(A)$ is essentially of finite type with this definition then the map of rings $A \to B$ is essentially of finite type in the sense of EGA.